# select variable number of tokens from pandas column based on tuples in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns: `sentence` containing text and `selector` containing arrays of tuples of varying lengths.

Consider the following data frame as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['KEEP some of the words from this sentence.',
                                'Keep SOME of THE words from this sentence.',
                                'KEEP some OF the WORDS from this sentence.',
                                'Keep SOME of THE words FROM this SENTENCE.'],
                   'selector': [[(10, 0, 1)],
                                [(10, 1, 2), (10, 3, 4)],
                                [(10, 0, 1), (10, 2, 3), (10, 4, 5)],
                                [(10, 1, 2), (10, 3, 4), (10, 5, 6), (10, 7, 8)]]})
```

I now want to select the words from `sentence` at the position indicated by the second element in each tuple (ignoring the `10` in each tuple). E.g. for the first row, I want the token in column `sentence` at the second position of all tuples (of which there is only one: `(10, 0, 1)`), i.e. the token at position `0`: `KEEP`. (For clarity, I have spelled all words to be selected in ALL CAPS).

I would like to get a dataframe looking like this:

```
sentence                                    selector                                           selected_tokens
KEEP some of the words from this sentence.  [(10, 0, 1)],                                      ['KEEP']
KEEP some OF the WORDS from this sentence.  [(10, 0, 1), (100, 2, 3), (10, 4, 5)],             ['KEEP', 'OF', 'WORDS']
Keep SOME of THE words from this sentence.  [(10, 1, 2), (10, 3, 4)],                          ['SOME', 'THE']
Keep SOME of THE words FROM this SENTENCE.  [(10, 1, 2), (10, 3, 4), (10, 5, 6), (10, 7, 8)],  ['SOME', 'THE', 'FROM', 'SENTENCE']
```

Accessing the first token works well using `df['tok0_pos'] = df['selector'].str[0].str[1]` for the positions and `df['words0'] = [txt.split()[loc] for txt, loc in zip(df['sentence'], df['tok0_pos'])]` for the tokens.
However, due to the variable lengths (the real data set contains 0-25 tuples in the column `selectors`), this crashes quickly or is tedious.

Can someone point out how to best attain the column `selected_tokens` in the sample dataset?

Comment: I didn't read completely but it seems you already have the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

```
df["selected_tokens"] = [[sent[s] for _, s, _ in select] for sent, select in zip(df["sentence"].str.split(), df["selector"])]
print(df["selected_tokens"])
```

**Output**

```
0                          [KEEP]
1                     [SOME, THE]
2               [KEEP, OF, WORDS]
3    [SOME, THE, FROM, SENTENCE.]
Name: selected_tokens, dtype: object
```

An alternative solution, is to use numpy to take advantage of the advance indexing features:

```
import numpy as np

sentences = df["sentence"].str.split().apply(np.array)
indices = [[s[1] for s in select] for select in df["selector"]]
df["selected_tokens"] = [sentence[i] for sentence, i in zip(sentences, indices)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def get_word_at_index(sentence, index):
    return [sentence.split()[i[1]] for i in index]

df.loc[:, 'selected_tokens'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_word_at_index(x["sentence"], x["selector"]), axis=1)
```